# change the color of chart d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I am working with d3 js and dimpel js I have a line chart code here it works great but when I want to change the color of point in the this line chart it wont change what's wrong      here!!any help would be grateful
html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="chartContainer"></div>
</body>
<script src="js/d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/dimple.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 600, 400),
            data = [
                { "Value" : 100000, "Year" : 2009 },
                { "Value" : 110000, "Year" : 2010 },
                { "Value" : 100, "Year" : 2011 },
                { "Value" : 140000, "Year" : 2012 },
                { "Value" : 120000, "Year" : 2013 },
                { "Value" : 140000, "Year" : 2014 }
            ];

    var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
    var x = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Year");
    x.addOrderRule("Year");
    var y = chart.addCategoryAxis("y", "Value");
   //this line have dosen't work!!!!
   chart.addColorAxis("Value", ["green", "yellow", "red"]);
    var lines = chart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line);
    lines.lineWeight = 5;
    lines.lineMarkers = true;
    chart.draw();
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having stems from the fact that you are adding a y-axis as a [*`categoryAxis`*](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.chart#addCategoryAxis) instead of a [*`measureAxis`*](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.chart#addMeasureAxis). If you change `y` to a `measureAxis`, then your code works perfectly:

```
var y = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Value");
```

Here's a screenshot of the result:

[image]

Comment: Ah - you just beat me to it! Anyway, here's a jsfiddle with the same solution: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/L0xjjcnn/2/

Comment: @mdml thanks for your answer yes I got it.sorry for my silly question I am new in dimple js and d3 js